# JSON Array: PHP Warning: array_count_values(): Can only count STRING and INTEGER values

Tags: php, arrays, json

I've had a look at other questions and still can't figure this one out.

I have some iso country codes in the following json format:

```
[
  {
    "code": "ZA"
  },
  {
    "code": "VN"
  },
  {
    "code": "IN"
  },
  {
    "code": "AO"
  },
  {
    "code": "IN"
  },
  {
    "code": "IN"
  }
]
```

I'm trying to count the values using `array_count_values` but it's failing on a larger data set and I don't know why.

My code:

This works (small data set):

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

$json = file_get_contents('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/colinwilson/975c8a8509443b9c9b662816189c5012/raw/19743e79e51b59563750fe2db4283d1c95eb8023/data_sm.json');

$json = json_decode($json, true);

$json = array_count_values(array_column($json, "code"));

print_r($json);

result:

Array
(
    [ZA] => 1
    [VN] => 1
    [IN] => 3
    [AO] => 1
)
```

This doesn't (larger data set):

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

$json = file_get_contents('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/colinwilson/33994f94111321963dd8abd5ed6607b0/raw/e36ba410bdf9d0fefe9c057a90e93b52cf00c267/data.json');

$json = json_decode($json, true);

$json = array_count_values(array_column($json, "code"));

print_r($json);

result:

PHP Warning:  array_count_values(): Can only count STRING and INTEGER values! in C:\Users\colinwilson\Downloads\json_test.php on line 10

Warning: array_count_values(): Can only count STRING and INTEGER values! in C:\Users\colinwilson\Downloads\json_test.php on line 10
Array
(
    [ZA] => 16
    [VN] => 187
    [IN] => 114
    [AO] => 5
    [TN] => 16
    [HK] => 2
    [LB] => 10
    [BG] => 18
.......
```

What is happening to cause the warning on the larger data set? And how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is right here in the source data:

```
{
    "code": null
},
```

Adding an [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to the mix will resolve it:

```
$json = array_count_values(array_filter(array_column($json, "code")));
```

If you don't pass a `callable` to `array_filter()`, it will just filter out elements that are falsy, like `null`.

Comment: OMG. I swear I ran a search for null and found nothing! Don't I feel stupid! Thank you. EDIT: Will accept as soon as the time limit allows.

Comment: Funny how there is one item of, I don't know 1000? that is null.

Comment: Thanks for including info regarding `array_filter()`

Answer (score 0):

The error message should be read. Your data contains something that is not a string or integer.

```
$data = [
    'ZA' => 16,
    'VN' => 187,
    'xx' => []
];

array_count_values($data);
```

Outputs the same error message as the array contains an element that is not a string or integer.